# Query to show new sales growth for current year

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find new sales for this year, defined as new customers we sold to this year and not last, or new items we sold to existing customers this year that we didn't sell last year.

```
select sales1.Rep, sum(sales1.InvPrice) as newsales from sales sales1
where YEAR(sales1.InvDate)=YEAR(CURDATE()) and not exists (select 1
from sales sales2
where YEAR(sales2.InvDate)=YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1, YEAR)) and 
CONCAT(sales1.CustNo, sales1.Item)=CONCAT(sales2.CustNo, sales2.Item) limit 1)
group by sales1.Rep
```

The query returns sales dollars for each rep, but it takes over an hour to run.  Is there a better way to write this query so that it won't take so long?  My sales table has approximately 600,000 rows in it from 1/1/2017 to current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, but do you have the right indexes.
if not please post the EXPLAIN from the Query.

```
SELECT sales1.Rep
        , sum(sales1.InvPrice) as newsales
FROM sales sales1
WHERE sales1.InvDate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-01-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-12-31 23:59:59')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM sales sales2
            WHERE sales2.InvDate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR '%Y-01-01 00:00:00')
                                AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR,'%Y-12-31 23:59:59')
            AND ( sales1.CustNo = sales2.CustNo AND sales1.Item = sales2.Item)
            LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY sales1.Rep;
```

Comment: Thank you!  That cut the time down from about an hour to just a few minutes.

Comment: check the index or post the explain of the query. the time is to much

Comment: id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra 
1 | PRIMARY | sales1 | index | NULL | Rep | 768 | NULL | 569173 | Using where 
2 | DEPENDENT | SUBQUERY | sales2 | ref | CustNo | CustNo | 768 | asi.sales1.CustNo | 265 | Using where

Comment: thanks, can you also send the output from **show create table sales;** to see what indexes are exists